# NSSpeechSynthesizer class called inside ViewController in Cocoa framework is not producing desired output

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have a Mac OS X application with a ViewController which is invoking the NSSpeechSynthesizer class as follows -

```
- (IBAction)speakButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    NSString *mystring = [self.textFieldTextInput stringValue];

    self.speechSynth = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] initWithVoice:nil];

    if ([mystring length] ==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"string from %@ is of zero length", self.textFieldTextInput);


    }
    [self.speechSynth startSpeakingString:mystring];
    NSLog(@"Speech output end");

}
```

The textFieldInput and speakButtonTapped are wired using IB in Xcode 4.5.2

However, I am not getting the desired output (aka speech).

Comment: Unless your string is nil, looks good to me.  Perhaps the volume on your Mac is down?

Comment: No. I typed > say Hello on the command line and it works ok so not a volume issue. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: How did u declare speechSynth?

Comment: For some reason, my delegate method -(void) speechSynthesizer:(NSSpeechSynthesizer*)sender
        didFinishSpeaking:(BOOL)complete; is not getting called.

Comment: Of course it's not being called, you're not the thing's delegate.

Comment: But I added myself as the delegate in awakeFromNib - - (void) awakeFromNib
{
 NSDate *now;
 now = [NSDate date];
 [textField setObjectValue:now];
 
 self.speechSynthesizer = [[NSSpeechSynthesizer alloc] initWithVoice:nil];
 
 self.speechSynthesizer.delegate = self;
 

}

Comment: And do you also have something like this in the relevant header-file? : @interface DigiVoiceSpeechKit : NSObject < NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate >

Comment: Ok. And speechSynth is a (strong) property ?

Comment: Oh, BTW, I believe the delegate has to be set every time after allocating a new NSSpeechSynthesizer.